# ActionScript: How to add dynamically loaded addresses to entries on a dynamically loaded menu?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

So I have a menu with options that load dynamically from an XML file and that works pretty well. They've all got eventListeners attached for MouseOvers and that's good too. The place where I'm having an issue is I need to add a Click eventListener to each one that will load the appropriate content for that option. Each option should load the same page with variable content according to the address specified for that option. I've got the addresses listed with each option inside the XML file, and I've pushed them into an array. I just can't wrap my head around how to get the options to reference them. Here's my code so far:

```as
var blogData:XMLList;
var blogTotal:Number;

var entryTitle:String;

//Arrays
var entriesArray:Array = new Array();
var entryAddr:Array = new Array();

var blogListLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
blogListLoader.load(new URLRequest("BlogEntries.xml"));
blogListLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadBlogList);

function loadBlogList(e:Event):void
{
    var blogList:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    blogData = blogList.ENTRY;
    blogTotal = blogData.length();
}


function loadBlogEntries():void
{
    //Load entriesArray
    var yTmp:Number = 0;
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < blogTotal; i++)
    {
        var entryName = blogData[i].@TEXT;
        var entry:TextField = new TextField();
        entriesArray[i] = entry;
        entriesArray[i].textColor = 0x0DAC54;
        entriesArray[i].x = 0;
        entriesArray[i].y = yTmp;
        entriesArray[i].width = 1031;
        entriesArray[i].height = 90.30;
        entriesArray[i].embedFonts = true;
        entriesArray[i].antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        entriesArray[i].defaultTextFormat = listformat;
        entriesArray[i].selectable = false;
        entriesArray[i].wordWrap = true;
        entriesArray[i].text = entryName;
        entriesArray[i].autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        entriesArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER , bEntryOvr);
        entriesArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , bEntryClick);
        BlogPage.blogEntriesPage.entryList.addChild(entriesArray[i]);
        yTmp = yTmp + 149;

        var Addr = blogData[i].@ADDR;
        entryAddr[i] = Addr;
    }
}

function bEntryOvr(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.backgroundColor = 0x0DAC54;
    event.target.background = true;
    event.target.textColor = 0x000000;
    event.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT , bEntryOut);
}

function bEntryOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.background = false;
    event.target.textColor = 0x0DAC54;
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT , bEntryOut);
}

function bEntryClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    showPage = BlogPage.blogEntriesPage.blogEntry;
    flashup();
}
```

I don't imagine it's probably that hard, but it's currently blowing my mind. Any insights are appreciated.
Thanks,
-T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a closure:

```as
entriesArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeEntryClick(index));
```

```as
function makeEntryClick(index:Number):Function {
    return function (event:MouseEvent):void {
        bEntryClick(event, index);
    };
}

function bEntryClick(event:MouseEvent, index:Number):void {
    // ...
}
```

If you need to remove the handler later, you could pass along `arguments.callee`.

Comment: Oh man, that looks pro. Like, Leonardo DiCaprio's in a dream inside a dream inside the matrix style pro. I'm going to have to stare at that a while before I get what you're doing there. Inline functions. I heard those are bad for your health... or something.

Comment: I rewrote it to use an explicit function instead. It looks a little better. An inline function is required to capture the value of the iteration variable (`i`)`.

Comment: Okay, I think I can start to make sense of what you're doing here. Although it will take a but of squinting and temple rubbing, it looks like a quick and elegant solution. Thanks!